# How to remove this error (Undefined control sequence. \def\baselinestretch{1}\chapter)

Tags: undefined

I am writing my article in report format and i have to use format. `Undefined control sequence. \def\baselinestretch{1}\chapter`
 in my thesis. Need help to resolve this problem

Comment: `\chapter` is not defined in the `article` class.

Comment: But is defined in `report`. The question in unclear and there are not enough clues to solve the problem. Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).